# Mysql: auto increment one column based on another column

Tags: mysql

Please Help with my problem in mysql.
How to change auto increment to different value if one of the column has the same value.. For example

When inserting new value in table. if **x_id is 1** then my **id is 1** and so on. if **x_id is 2** then **my id is 1** .. (**id is Auto increment.**)

this is my expected reult.

[image]

Sorry for my bad English.
Thank You.  :)

Comment: Given your sample data, what are your expected results?  A little confused still...

Comment: i already edited my question..

Comment: That feature is available in MyISAM, but not in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate `x_id`.  If so, you need a column that specifies the *ordering* of the rows.

Then, one method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.id,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.?? <= t.??) as x_id
from t;
```

The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

`autoincrement` values are mostly used for primary keys in MySQL. As you can not add a PK on `id` column (due to duplicate values) it only means you are doing something very wrong.

Of course you can always come up with some function to return the expected value, but personally I would not bother. Re-think your design before inventing something this uncommon.

I.e. if these object are not supposed to share the same primary key then why are they stored in the same table at all?